# What is the meaning of saying that the expectation of a bernoulli random variable is equal to the probability of success?

Tags: probability

When we talk about expectation then it means that which is the highly probable value that the random variable can take and it must be a natural no  ,now in case of bernoulli random variable if probability of success is $p$ and probability of failure is $1-p$ , so expectation $= p$.

Now $p$ is a number between $0$ and $1$ but in general the random variable can take any two values either $0$ or $1$ so then what is the actual meaning of this result?

Comment: The expected value is not a "highly probable value that the random variable can take".  It is the average value that the variable takes over many trials.  As your example shows it doesn't even have to be a possible value for the variable.

Comment: Likewise the expected value of the number of dots on the top face of a usual die when one throws the die is 3.5, a value which appears on no face of the die since it is not even an integer.

Comment: @lulu , as you said that it is the average value that the variable can take over many trials ,now what is the use of this value when it is not a natural number ,I am a bit confused in this

Comment: An average is a useful concept!  Say your $p=.1$, just to be specific.  Then if you play the game often your "expected" outcome is the same as if you just got $.1$ on each play.  Now, of course, the average doesn't tell you everything you need to know.  If you play $100$ times you expect to "win" on $10$ trials but there is some probability that you'll win only on $9$ and so on.  Thus, people also look at variance (or, equivalently, standard deviation).  Those two numbers also don't tell you everything but they are a good start.